# Get text inside of a span

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have an HTML page with this code

```
<span class="titoloSerie" style="font-size: 40px; color: #000000;">SHOW NAME</span>
```

I want to get "SHOW NAME". I tried the following code, but it didn't work:

```
var div = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='titoloSerie']");
```

The compiler interrupts saying "div is null" (ok, I didn't handle the exception but I know it).

The following code is:

```
List<string> pageTitles = new List<string>();
foreach (var title in div)
{
    pageTitles.Add(title.InnerText);
}
```

The compiler quits in the foreach loop at "div" saying it's null.

Comment: If i test your sample string i get "SHOW NAME": `div.First().InnerText` or `doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='titoloSerie']").InnerText`

Comment: Lets say i have tons of <span></span>
I can't use SelectSingleNode, i need all of them

Comment: I tried your code and it's working fine. Does your HTML page is correctly loaded?

Comment: How can i check it? I think it is, i have several other functions of this type working in the same application

Comment: @Weizen: don't post your expected html snippet but the real. Maybe you can post the complete html page or at least a larger part. Have you used the debugger, how do you load the `HtmlDocument`?

Comment: `HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://www.subsfactory.it/?s="+sbl[0].ToString());`

Comment: What's the value of `sbl[0]`?

Comment: An id of the current show i'm searching for. Let's say for example the page is `http://www.subspedia.tv/serie.php?id=315`

Comment: That's not helping very much. It would be a lot easier to find your problem if you provide the html page you're parsing.

Comment: I just gave the link to you in the previous post. I'm trying to parse all the span tags in that page

Comment: @Weizen: "for example" is wrong, you want that we help you to find the reason for the issue. Since the html page doesn't seem to contain that span it depends on the real html page not an arbitrary.

Comment: I'm serious, that's the page i'm trying to parse. I need the Show Name (first span, class=titoloSerie) and the episodes, the text inside the span inside the "td" tag with class=rigaStagioneSerie

Comment: There's no such class as `titoloSerie` in the page at `http://www.subsfactory.it/`. If you're loading another page with your parameter `sbl[0]`, I could not imagine your page url. I wil not load all the pages of your site to find the right one!

Comment: I alredy wrote that the url is exactly `http://www.subspedia.tv/serie.php?id=315`

Comment: Well, it's working for me with this url: `http://www.subspedia.tv/serie.php?id=315`. I found: "Heroes Reborn"

Comment: @TimSchmelter well guy, i can confirm that the URL i provided contains at least 10 "rigaStagioneSerie"

Comment: @krlzlx i keep getting a null "div" variable. Can you explain me why the code works in your compiler but not in mine?

Comment: @Weizen: not `http://www.subsfactory.it/` but `http://www.subspedia.tv/serie.php?id=315`. So the former page doesn't contain such spans with that classes only  the latter does.

Comment: You said: `titoloSerie` not `rigaStagioneSerie`..........

Comment: I need to get both, but i can't get none of them.
You said you made the code work to get "Heroes reborn". How did you write it?

Comment: @krlzlx you may want to use https://dotnetfiddle.net/ to share the working demo example

Comment: @har07: https://dotnetfiddle.net/I3Y0zf (so the same code OP used)

Comment: Fixed it, thanks you all!

Comment: @Weizen: so what was causing the problem then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var rigaStagioneSerie = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='rigaStagioneSerie']");
List<string> pageTitles = new List<string>();

foreach (var title in rigaStagioneSerie)
{
    if (title.ChildNodes.Count == 1)
    {
        pageTitles.Add(title.InnerText.Replace("\n", string.Empty).Replace("\t", string.Empty));
    }

}

var titoloSerie = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='titoloSerie']");

foreach (var title in titoloSerie)
{
    pageTitles.Add(title.InnerText);
}
```

Try it here: [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YTVHsc)